# How to make results from previous rows values in TSQL or Power Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powerquery

I have a table, in the table i have for example 4 columns

(ID(for example 12 different ID repeating for 10000 rows but then +26 added for the next 10000 rows), 
Date (ordered by this -can't be changed-),
Error(-1,0,1), 
ItemName,

What should i do if i want to make my query warn me if there were 3 error for the same ID right after each other 
(It's not sure that the rows are actually right after each other, because the whole table ordered by Date, so ID 1 can be in the first row and then the 13th and then the 25th for example) ?

Comment: What database are you using are you using MySQL or SQL server? "T-SQL (Transact Structured Query Language) is the extension of SQL functionality supported by Sybase ASE and Microsoft SQL Server. Do **not** use this tag for MySQL, PostgreSql, Oracle(Pl/SQL) related queries"

Comment: Sample data would be helpful. It sounds like you want 3 consecutive errors for the same ID ordered by date, but if you have two errors, a good one, and then another error you don’t care.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: SQL server. 
And yes @StuartAinsworth That's the point. Anytime if i have 3 errors right after each other in time, i want to sign it with something like "3 errors in a row" or smth like that.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understand, you need Items which has 3 errors and it is in consecutive lines on order by date.
Please refer my code and this support sql server

```
/*create table*/
CREATE TABLE YourTable( PK_Id   int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) primary key,
                        ID      int NOT NULL,
                        CreatedDate datetime NOT NULL,
                        Error   int NOT NULL,
                        ItemName    nvarchar(100) NULL);
/*sample data 1*/
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES (1, '2018-10-13 10:10:10', -1, 'Item-1'),
                             (2, '2018-10-13 10:10:15', -1, 'Item-2'),
                             (3, '2018-10-13 10:10:17', -1, 'Item-3'),
                             (4, '2018-10-13 10:10:17', -1, 'Item-4'),
                             (1, '2018-10-14 10:10:10', 0, 'Item-1'),
                             (2, '2018-10-14 10:10:15', 0, 'Item-2'),
                             (3, '2018-10-14 10:10:17', 0, 'Item-3'),
                             (4, '2018-10-14 10:10:17', 0, 'Item-4'),
                             (1, '2018-10-15 10:10:10', 1, 'Item-1'),
                             (2, '2018-10-15 10:10:15', 1, 'Item-2'),
                             (3, '2018-10-15 10:10:17', 1, 'Item-3'),
                             (4, '2018-10-15 10:10:17', 1, 'Item-4')
/*sample data 2*/
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES (5, '2018-10-16 10:10:10', -1, 'Item-5'),
                             (5, '2018-10-16 10:10:15', 0, 'Item-5'),
                             (5, '2018-10-16 10:10:17', 1, 'Item-5')


SELECT Id, ItemName
  FROM YourTable
 GROUP BY Id, ItemName
HAVING COUNT(Error) = 3                 /*check number of errors*/
   AND SUM(Error) = 0                   /*check all 3 errors*/
   AND SUM(PK_Id) = MIN(PK_Id) * 3 + 3  /*check right after each error*/
```

Comment: So my table looks like this:

ID     Date                                 Laser_ID    Error          Item_name
1  '2018-10-03 10:10:10.000'        1               -1           random_item
2  '2018-10-03 10:10:11.000'        2               1            random_item (The same as before)

So basically, there are 1-36 laser scanners with ID, and if the same laser make an "error (1/-1)" for  3 times in a row, i need a new column where it shows me that 3 error happened. But i have to take care about the Date, and also that it has to be with different Items

Comment: Can you create table with data as I did in the post? and tell us output should look like. How to identify errors, what are the possible error codes etc. Then we can understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started; use the LAG() function in SQL Server 2012+ to determine the value in the previous row, and the row before that (there may be a way to do this in one pass rather than two, like I'm doing).  This will return the last row in a sequence of three errors (assuming -1 is the error code).

```
USE tempdb;

CREATE TABLE Logs (ID int, Dt datetime, error int, itemname varchar(20))
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cx ON LOGS (dt)


INSERT INTO LOGS
VALUES (1, '20180101', -1, 'error'),
(1, '20180102', -1, 'error'),
(1, '20180103', -1, 'error'),
(1, '20180104', 0, 'no error'),
(2, '20180102', -1, 'error'),
(2, '20180103', -1, 'error'),
(2, '20180104', 0, 'no error'),
(2, '20180105', -1, 'error')


; with c AS (
SELECT *
    , LAG(error, 1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Dt) prv1
    , LAG(error, 2,0) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Dt) prv2
FROM Logs
)
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE error = prv1 and error = prv2
    AND error = -1


DROP TABLE Logs
```